# How to check if a process is running under Rosetta with terminal

Tags: macos-big-sur, apple-silicon, rosetta

I know that one can use Activity Monitor to check if a process is running via Rosetta on Apple Silicon. I wonder if there is a way to do the same with the terminal?

Edit:

The process is some other application, so if there is a way to check if this process is running in Rosetta a possible command could maybe have the syntax:

`$ is_running_under_rosetta <pid>`

which would output

`yes` or `no`.

Answer (score 32):

By using following command you can check if the process is running under Rosetta(1) or not(0, natively).

```
sysctl -n sysctl.proc_translated
```

Answer (score 22):

Confirm that you are using the Native Terminal by typing `arch`, which should return arm64: [Terminal app screenshot running `arch` command and returning `arm64`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Oak.png)